# Join multiple tables to find the tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table1

```
cat_id | post_id
1         2
2         1
3         1
1         3
1         4
```

Table2

```
post_id | tag
1         tag1
2         tag2
3         tag3
```

I need to get the tags for a specific category id. Ex: `cat_id = 1`.

How can I do that?

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: What have you tried? Try something, show your effort. Share a link of something you read and didn't understand. We'll be glad to help, but most of the work should come from you.

Answer (score 3):

you can join the two tables on post_id

```
SELECT t2.tag 
FROM   table1 t1 
       INNER JOIN table2 t2 
               ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
WHERE  t1.cat_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try it.

```
SELECT tag 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT post_id 
                   FROM   table1 
                   WHERE  cat_id = 1)
```